# ArangoDB traverse getting the vertex documents

Tags: graph, traversal, arangodb

How can I traverse a graph getting the complete vertex related documents?

I don't want only the vertex related IDs from a start ID, but also the complete document (all fields) from all IDs related with the start node ID.

Today I get the vertex and query all the related vertex one by one, because I need all document fields from the related vertexes.

Thanks.
Ralf

Comment: Did the answer fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Using the [modern AQL graph traversal](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/graphs/traversals/), the full vertex documents are returned by default.

---

You're able to retrieve the full vertices documents by specifying the `includeVertices` option (see docs about graph functions) for more details)